# Multiple 1st-party jar files and multiple log4j2 configurations under a web application

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2

If you have multiple 1st-party log4j2 configurations, say in src/main/resources.  How can you setup your logging configurations to be separate from each other and so they don't conflict.

My thought process right now is to have two different file configurations and not define the ROOT node and specify the different packages.

I have also tried having two different conf files.  log4j2.xml and log4j2-test.xml but this would only work for two libraries.  Does log4j2-myapp.xml work?   The documentation says use a System property log4j.file=  but this wouldn't work because I want both configuration files.  Also, sometimes we don't have control over the system properties for this web container.

How can I solve the problem of multiple log4j2 configurations.

Log4j2 version, java8, websphere container, multiple 1stparty jars.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logserverdir">defaultvm2</Property>
    </Properties>
    <!-- Log4j2 configuration, use with greylog -->
    <Appenders>        
        <RollingFile name="MainApiCommonsAppenderApi" fileName="/usr/local/pfs/logs/defaultvm2/log4j_api.log"           
                filePattern="/usr/local/pfs/logs/defaultvm2/log4j_api.%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] -- [%X{mdcLogSessionId} - %-5p - %C{1}.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="140MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />     
        </RollingFile>          
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.primerica.pfn" level="info" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="MainApiCommonsAppenderApi" />
                <AppenderRef ref="GraylogCommons" /> 
        </Logger>     
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="debug" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="MainApiCommonsAppenderApi" />
                <AppenderRef ref="GraylogCommons" /> 
        </Logger>          
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: it's a bit unclear, because the single application uses single logging properties. How would you like the multiple logging configuration files to override their properties within scope of one application?

Comment: Would the [`XInclude`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-341) work so that you could provide the main configuration file and include the others. This would allow to not have to worry about the other files if they update as you'd simply be including them.

Comment: The single application uses multiple logging properties.  I don't want them to override each other.  It would be nice if there was: lib1:log4j2-lib1.xml , lib2: log4j2-lib2.xml

Comment: XInclude may work

Comment: You might consider using [composite configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.6.1/manual/configuration.html#CompositeConfiguration). In general my thought is that an application as a whole should define its logging configuration not individual libraries. The library does not know how it is being used, the application does know how it uses the library. Maybe application A uses classes R and S and wants to see detailed messages from them while application B uses classes X and Y and needs to log messages from those.

Comment: Yea, to your point, I have multiple 1st party and third-party and they have their own log4j2.xml configurations.  Hard to control how they put their' configuration files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, this was the best answer:

"You might consider using composite configuration. In general my thought is that an application as a whole should define its logging configuration not individual libraries. The library does not know how it is being used, the application does know how it uses the library. Maybe application A uses classes R and S and wants to see detailed messages from them while application B uses classes X and Y and needs to log messages from those"